# My Python IDLE is missing the Debugging menu

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.4, python-idle

I thought it was coming by default with the IDLE but I don't have it.

By the way, I installed Python 3.4.

A few researches on the net revealed themselves unfruitful. Any idea about what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: Are you openning IDLE shell?

Comment: If it really isn't there it sounds like an outright bug in installation. I have Python 3.4 and have no such problem. Perhaps you can reinstall and see what happens. But first -- make sure that you are looking at the shell and not the edit window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be opening the code window not the shell window..
Try opening the shell window..
It has a Debug menu(the shell window) but the code window does not have one..

Comment: Ok I didn't know the "Edit with IDLE" was different in that regard. That was the one I was using.

Comment: Kind of unpractical and unintuitive the way the default debuggers works but it will do… Thanks for your help.

Comment: Debug menu is only displayed for Shell because 3 of 4 items are not applicable to edit windows and would have to be grayed out if Debug were added to editors.  The 4th, 'Debugger' displays `DEBUG ON` in Shell.  However, I agree that it would be nice to be able to turn the debugger on from the editor.  I will have to look and see if this would be techically feasible.